# AWS Bitnami WordPress - Change Install Directory

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache2, bitnami

I can't find how bitnami knows to use the apps/wordpress directory as the default WordPress location.

I checked /opt/bitnami/apache2/httpd.conf but there is literally nothing in there mentioning the word app or WordPress.

So how does bitnami know to default to the WordPress directory in the apps folder?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the file `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` , it includes `http-prefix.conf' of your wordress application.

Attached screenshot of my application, as example
[image]

If you want to create your own PHP application in bitnami, this link might help. https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/php/#how-to-create-a-custom-php-application

Comment: This is the only symbolic link I can find. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1eQrD3UKsY7clVtcUxKWms2bmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Here is my apache2 folder, and conf folder.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1eQrD3UKsY7Tkd0TWxxN0dDR00/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1eQrD3UKsY7N2FuOEVvb1RPUk0/view?usp=sharing

Sorry I cut the conf image short, but it doesn't have any links.

Comment: @Subtopic I apologize, understood your question wrong. Updated the answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: So what I did was cp my wordpress directory into a new directory, let's call it  newsite.com. I then changed that Include that you are mentioning above to instead of be in drupal/conf/httpd-prefix.conf to newsite.com/conf/httpd-prefix.conf. I then go into that file, and update the file so the DocumentRoot doesn't point to the drupal directory, but my new directory, then the same for the includes line at the bottom of the file to point at my new directory. But when I restart apache, my site breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami developer here.

The configuration of Apache is based on including some configuration files in others. Mainly, joining the most important, the resulting configuration file would look something like this:

```
# App url moved to root
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /<none> / [L,R]

<IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
  <Proxy "unix:/opt/bitnami/php/var/run/wordpress.sock|fcgi://wordpress-fpm" timeout=300>
  </Proxy>
</IfDefine>

<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs">
  Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None

  <IfVersion < 2.3 >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </IfVersion>

  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
    Require all granted
  </IfVersion>

  <IfDefine USE_PHP_FPM>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://wordpress-fpm"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfDefine>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [S=1]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</Directory>
```

As you can see, `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs` is the default location.

[EDIT] I add more information:

You can install several applications in the same instance/server, for example, you can have in the same instance Wordpress and Drupal. In this case, both applications will be using the same Apache.

So we provide two configurations branches:

- **Apache** configuration (`/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/`).
- **Applications** configuration (`/opt/bitnami/apps/APP/conf/`) in your case, you only have wordpress so `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/`.

Due to WordPress configuration is included in Apache configuration and taking into account that lower levels (applications = wordpress) overwrite the Apache configuration, so DocumentRoot, Directory, etc. those related to the application prevails.

A very simplified scheme would be:

**Apache branch**

```
/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/
        |----> bitnami
                |----> bitnami-apps-prefix.conf    Include ../wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf
                |----> bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf      
                |----> bitnami.conf                Include bitnami-apps-prefix.conf        DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
                |----> httpd.conf                  Symlink to instance type
        |----> httpd.conf                          Include bitnami/bitnami.conf            DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs" <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs">
                                                   Include bitnami/bitnami/httpd.conf
```

**WordPress branch**

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/
    |----> banner.conf
    |----> htaccess.conf                                    Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/..."
    |----> httpd-app.conf         Include htaccess.conf     Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    |----> httpd-prefix.conf      Include httpd-app.conf    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
    |----> httpd-vhosts.conf      Include httpd-app.conf    VirtualHost {DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"}
```

Comment: See that makes sense to me. But when I go into /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

`DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"`

is the DocumentRoot.

Comment: And htdocs doesn't have any symlinks in it. But at the bottom of apache2/conf/httpd.conf check this out. `Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf"`

`Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/httpd.conf"`